# asp.net mvc controller calculating incorrect values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

this is seriously bugging me right now. I have the following controller action method:

```
public PartialViewResult ScrollEmployeeCompYear(int employeeid, string direction, int latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed)
{
    List<EmployeeCompensationYear> fourYearsList = new List<EmployeeCompensationYear>();
    Employee Employee = _db.Employees.Find(employeeid);
    EmployeeCompensationYear compyear;
    if (direction == "right")
    {
        int latestYearDisplayedMinusThree = latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed - 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if ((compyear = Employee.CompensationYear.Find(m => m.Year == --latestYearDisplayedMinusThree)) != null)
            {
                fourYearsList.Add(compyear);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        fourYearsList.Reverse();
    }
    else if (direction == "left")
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if ((compyear = Employee.CompensationYear.Find(m => m.Year == ++latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed)) != null)
            {
                fourYearsList.Add(compyear);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return PartialView(fourYearsList);
}
```

there are two problems, I'm calling this method from an Html.Ajax helper and the "latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed" is returning 2020 (which I have in the database for employee.compensationYear). By the way I have data from the year 2014 to 2020 for this model in the database.

so anyway, first problem, when 2020 is returned, and I get the direction "right", I'm creating a new int variable that gets 2020-3 which should equal 2017. Then in the loop, in the if, I'm assigning compeer to the employee's compensationYear where the year is equal to "--latestYearDisplayedMinusThree". This should subtract 1 from 2017 first, then assign it, but its not, for some reason, in my first item in the list I'm getting 2015 not 2016.

the other problem is, when I'm getting "left" and 2015 as my latest displayed year, its going into the `else if (direction == "left")` which is great, but then its returning null for where I assign compyear, even though I have ++2015 (again, I have 2014 to 2020).

have I done something wrong in the code here??

Comment: how many items you have in your fourYearsList? Since you reverse fourYearsList, so the first item in that list might be result of 2nd iteration of the loop, which is 2015

Comment: @DavidTansey but I'm assigning, not comparing

Comment: @PhuongNguyen I think a new instance of the controller is created every time I "submit" from view to controller, so if I reverse for one submit, I think the second submit is independent therefore a new list is created for adding

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, You assumption is correct (a new instance is created)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for confirming

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I understand a new fourYearsList is created for each call to controller action. But your for loop runs for 4 times, each time you find something, you add it into the list and continue with next iteration, so it's possible that the for loop runs more than once, and add into the list more than one item

Comment: @PhuongNguyen I don't understand what you're saying, how can one of these for loops run more than once?

Comment: your for loop is starting from 0 to 3, let's say when i = 0, the Find() method returns some result (not null), you add it into the list and increment i = 1 since it's not break. When i = 1, suppose Find() method returns not null result also, it adds into the list and increment i = 2, and so on until i = 4. It only breaks the for loop if it doesn't find anything matching

Comment: are you trying to troll? thats the whole point of the for loop

Comment: yes, so it's possible that fourYearsList list contains more than one item after the for loop right? If it contains more than one item, your reverse method will make the first list item to be the last item found in your for loop

Comment: yea... so? what does that have to do with my problem? I'm still confused what you're trying to get at

Comment: If your for loop runs for 2 iteration, fourYearsList will contain 2016 and 2015 in that order. After reverse, fourYearsList will contain 2015 and 2016 in that order. So the first item is indeed 2015. That's why I'm asking how many items in your list

Comment: yes, correct, the list is reversed and the view is returned by the method, but then I try to "submit" again, and a new list is created independent of the first one that I "reversed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is how the unary (`++x` and `--x`) operators work inside the loops, and perhaps not doing what you expect them to do.

However if I understand what you want correctly, then this should simplify things a bit:

```
if (direction == "right")
{
    fourYearsList = Employee.CompensationYear.Where(m => m.Year <= (latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed - 4)).Take(4).ToList();
}
else if (direction == "left")
{
    fourYearsList = Employee.CompensationYear.Where(m => m.Year >= (latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed + 1)).Take(4).ToList();   
}
```

The start values `latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed - 4` and `latestYearCurrentlyDisplayed + 1` may need adjusting depending on what you want to display, and also the ordering depending how you want the list displayed.

Comment: looking into what take does, does this accommodate possible null values?

Comment: thank you, I changed the ++ and -- to += and -= and it worked!

Comment: @AbdulAhmad the take method will only pull whats available in the `IQueryable` list after the `Where` has been preformed. So the `Where` will preform the query first, and create a sub list from that, then `Take` will pull the first 4 elements in the list. Thus no chance of there being `null` elements in the list.